# NMAP nse script using python3

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

How will i pass the nse to the command?

import os
domain = "example.com"
nse = ["vulscan","vulners","xmpp-brute","xmpp-info","xmlrpc-methods","xdmcp-discover","unusual-port"]
os.system("nmap -v --script= nse " + domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few choices:

```
import os 

domain = "example.com" 

nse = ["vulscan","vulners","xmpp-brute","xmpp-info","xmlrpc-methods","xdmcp-discover","unusual-port"] 

for each_script in nse:
   os.system("nmap -v --script={} {}".format(each_script, domain)
```

But using `os.system` the command isn't cleaned. (Tip: read more on 'os' and 'sys' modules)

An safer alternative would be `subprocess`:
Sample:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('nmap', '-sS', 'example.com')
```

However, the best approach I would say, is to use the nmap library from Python.
Example:

```
import nmap #OR nmap3
nm=nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('example.com', '445', 
         arguments='--script=/usr/local/share/nmap/scripts/smb-os-discovery.nse')
```

Starting point [here](https://pypi.org/project/python3-nmap/).